# Recursive Unrar with Deletion as it progresses

Tags: bash, rar

Basically, i have a set of directories that are constantly being filled with .rar's, and i need to be able to extract them in place with automatic deletion of the left over .(rar|rXX) files. How would i go about this?

Note: I can't delete all of them once done, they have to be deleted as the script completes one rar set.

Example Directory Structure:

```
/
/folder1/
        /file1.rar
        /file1.r00
        /file1.r01
/folder2/
        /sub.folder1/
                    /file2.part001.rar (contains a directory "file2")
                    /file2.part002.rar
                    /file2.part003.rar
        /sub.folder2/
                    /file3.rar
                    /file3.r00
                    /file3.r01
```

Expected Result:

```
/
/folder1/
        /file1.ext
/folder2/
        /sub.folder1/
                    /file2/
                          /file2.ext
        /sub.folder2/
                    /file3.ext
```

Comment: i used: find ./software-foo*/ -type f -name '*01.rar' -execdir unrar x {} \ but it's missing the deletion and filled my hard drive.

Comment: Don't put the solution into the question please. Answer your own question as soon as you can (in about 7 hours) — this way, you can even accept it later on!

Comment: " I can't delete all of them once done, they have to be deleted as the script completes one rar set." - **Why exactly is this the case?"**

Comment: Disk would fill before it reached the end of processing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variant for Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -d "${1}" ]; then
    printf '%s: error: mandatory argument is not a valid directory.' "${0##*/}" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

shopt -s extglob
for i in "${1}"/**/*.rar; do
    cd -- "${i%/*}"
    file=${i##*/}
    unrar e -- "${file}" && rm -- @(${file}|${file%.rar}.r[[:digit:]][[:digit:]])
    cd - >/dev/null
done
```

RAR archives can also "legally" be named e.g. `myarchive.part001.rar` and so on, and that would have to be handled separately in some way if those kinds of archives exist. A pragmatic way of solving this is to replace

```
unrar e -- "${file}" && rm -- @(${file}|${file%.rar}.r[[:digit:]][[:digit:]])
```

with

```
unrar e -o- -- "${file}"
if [ $? -eq 0 -o $? -eq 10 ]; then
    rm -- @(${file}|${file%.rar}.r[[:digit:]][[:digit:]])
fi
```

but be wary of that this will clean out RAR files even if error code 10 ("No files to extract") is given, and is thus not generally recommended in its unmodified form.

---

All in all, it might be better to simply have the material stored in the archived form and instead use on-the-fly decompression or something similar when you want to use it. There might be other benefits to keeping the archived format.

Comment: +1, but why not use `for f in !(*.part[0-9][0-9][2-9].rar|!(*.rar)); do`? That will catch non-partXXX.rar files and part001.rar files only and spare you the error prone exit code check.

Comment: @kopischke: That would make that part better, but be at least just as error prone in other ways You assume `.part###.rar`, but they could just as well be `.part##.rar` or just `part#.rar`, and there are even more allowed naming schemes (`archive.001` -> `archive.002`, etc.), and the suffix length depends on the number of archives (`int(log10(#parts))+1`, really) (i.e. it could also be `.r101` which is not currently matched), so a general solution is more complex. This will still remain "just a quick hack", and the length one wants to go to handle special cases is up to the questioner.

Comment: The variable numeric part can be easily matched by nesting patterns: `for f in !(*.part*([0-9])[2-9].*|!(*.rar)); do`, but you are right that other legal naming schemes would need a more complex pattern. I’m still thinking finding a matching glob would probably be safer than exit code checking (better to miss some archives than delete stuff that shouldn’t be IMO) – but that decision is up to OP, agreed.

Comment: @kopischke: I did not know about the `+` operator in Bash extglob, thanks for the example.

Comment: Yup, extended globs, when nested, can be surprisingly powerful. I edited the comment to use the `*()` pattern (0 or more, instead of 1 or more – now also matches `.part#.rar`), BTW. And `.r101` is matched by the glob (first digit is in the 0-9 range).

Comment: Keeping the data compressed is not an option, as the next tool is unable to read the rar files, and never will be able to.

Comment: @Jharwood: One can redirect the output from RAR directly into a pipe for that matter, but of course it still might not be the most efficient way of doing things.

Comment: The issue with that is knowing before hand what file the application is going to process, this is why I need to get them all extracted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this off the top of my head, so it's untested code, but it should get you on the right track. It basically walks the tree you point it to, looking for .rar files. Upon finding one, it will uncompress it in place and delete the original archive unless unrar returns nonzero. When hitting a folder, the function will just call itself, causing it to be recursive.

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ ! -d "$1" ]] && echo "Please point me at a directory!" && exit 1

function recursively_extract_all_rars_in() {
    local x=`pwd` f
    cd "$1"


    for f in (*); do
        [[ -d "$f" ]] && recursively_extract_all_rars_in "$f"
        [[ -f "$f" ]] && [[ "$f" =~ "*.rar" ]] && unrar e "$f" && rm ${f%%.*}.r??
    done
    cd "$x"
}

recursively_extract_all_rars_in "$1"
```

The function name is completely arbitrary. I like to have them read like proper english when invoked with their arguments. `[[ -d /path ]]` returns true if the path exists and is a directory. `-f` does the corresponding for files. `[[ "string" =~ "pattern"]]` is a bashism that allows for pattern matching in strings. It works mostly just like glob patterns.

The line `local x=pwd f` might be cryptic, but it just defines two local variables: one called x, to hold the `pwd`, and one called f, uninitialized (it's initialized in the for loop below, I just declare it here so it's local).

Storing the `pwd` and returning to it if your function uses `cd` is a Good Thing (tm).

Please note that using the output of `ls` programatically is generally Bad Mojo, and you should avoid it like the pest, in favour of `find`. **If any of your file names contains a space, using ls in your script will screw up big time.** You have been warned.

### ZSH

I'm not sure you can do the same thing in Bash, but in ZSH, I'd put the following somewhere in `.zshrc`

```
function recursive_unrar() {
    for f in **/*.rar; do
        local cwd=`pwd` fbn=${f##*/}
        cd "${f%/*}"
        unrar e "$fbn"
        rm "${fbn%%.*}.r{01..99} $fbn"
        cd "$cwd"
    done
}
```

And then just call it from inside the corresponding folder.

Comment: This will delete the first rar of each set from what i can see, how can i get it to delete all from the directory?

Comment: /usr/bin/unrarall: line 12: conditional binary operator expected
/usr/bin/unrarall: line 12: syntax error near `~='
/usr/bin/unrarall: line 12: `        [[ -f "$f" ]] && [[ "$f" ~= "*.rar" ]] && print $x'  -- What? :s

Comment: replace ls with find $1 and fix the pattern matching, and i think it'll be fine. anyone know how to match all .r00 .r01 .r02 etc etc?

Comment: The bash pattern matching operator is `=~`, not `~=`, that causes the error. Also, for the reasons already given n the answer, do not use he output from `ls` – use a *glob* instead, i.e. ` for f in *; do`.

Comment: replace `"$f"` in the `rm` command with `${f%%.*}.r??` to have it remove all the rar parts too.

Comment: @kopischke I didn't know you could use globs like that. Awesome!

Comment: Or again, use a glob: `for f in *.r??`. If you set `extglob`, you can use `@(*.rar|*.r[[:digit:]][[:digit:]])`, which is more restrictive (`r??` maches `rmm` and others, too). This is **much faster** than using `find` to achieve the same result.

Comment: @kopischke the reason I didn't use a better pattern in the for-loop set is because I wanted to include folders in the set, so I could recurse into them in the same for loop. Of course, you could just have another loop just for folders after looping over files, but that seems wasteful to me.

Comment: Fixed up my answer based on comments, and added an example of what I'd do in zsh.

Comment: Oh, and drop the parens in he tbash glob – that was a mstke in my first comment.

Comment: @mkaito: [NB: consolidated comment – too many errors in the previous iterations] Aye, realized that, but wanted to point out the options (globs work for the `rm` command too, and brace patterns are part of glob expressions in bash too). You can even do the recursive directory globbing in bash if you use bash version 4 and have `globstar` set. Note you also have to remove the parens around the glob in bash – that was a mistake of mine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3653/discussion-between-mkaito-and-kopischke)